# How can I edit a specific object in ObservableList?

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, javafx

For example, I have an `ObservableList` which holds two strings:

```
string1 = "foo"
string2 = "bar"
```

I want to edit `string1` so that it becomes "foobaz".

How can I do that?

I've tried using `.set(int index, Object element)`, but it adds another element, instead of editing the element at that index.

Comment: What is the type of `ObserverList`?

Comment: `.set(int index, Object element)` should work. Can you add a code snippet on how you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried using `.set(int index, Object element)`, and now it works (?). So that means that I've basically solved my problem.

Thanks for the replies everyone, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to replace the `String` `foo` and `obsrverList` is an `ArrayList` of `String`-

```
int size = obsrverList.size();

for(int index=0; index<size; index++){

   if("foo".equals(observerList.get(index)){

      obsrverList.set(index, "foobaz");

   }

}
```

You have to set `String` instead of `Object` if `obsrverList` is an `ArrayList` of `String`.

Comment: [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) is different from `ArrayList`. It has almost the same methods though. You might want to change your Assumptions in your answer.